# Why well-know symbols are in Symbol and not in Reflect API

Tags: javascript, reflection, metaprogramming, symbols, reflect

I don't understand one thing about well-known symbols in Javascript. What is the reason of putting those well-known symbols into Symbol instead of Reflect API? For me seems that the right place for them is the Reflect API as the Reflect API is made for metaprogramming, particularly for reflection and particularly for introspection and self-modification? Does anyone knows the reason of doing so?

Comment: [Related](//google.com/search?q=well-known+symbols+site%253Aesdiscuss.org): [Does Symbol.split, Symbol.search etc. have to be in the Symbol namespace?](//esdiscuss.org/topic/does-symbol-split-symbol-search-etc-have-to-be-in-the-symbol-namespace). `Reflect` offers the default functionalities for the [Proxy traps](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy#handler_functions). It’s not entirely related to well-known symbols.

Comment: I was trying to answer the question you asked in a comment (re top-level `await`) when you deleted your question. If you run your code as `node filename.js`, `filename.js` is a module (either CommonJS or ESM, depending on whether you have `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`). If you have `"type": "module"`, then it's an ESM module and `await` works at the top level. If you want to run code **not** in a module in Node.js, you have to do `node < filename.js` (which won't work with top-level `await`).

Comment: yeah thank you Crowder, I got it myself from reading the links you have posted. that is why I have deleted the post. thank you again